# Is 'some other time's' expression correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say my friend is reading a book or an article and wants to know how old it is,  assuming there is no date printed on it.

Say he asks

> Is this last year's?

I reply

> No it is **some other time's**, it is definitely not last year's.

Is **some other time's** correct here in this expression? It sounds a bit odd to me. If it is not, can you please suggest an alternate expression.

Comment: I would rather answer with "No, it's older." which is shorter. The sentence you are using is a comma-splice: You are joining two independent clauses using the comma when a conjunction or another punctuation mark should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my own and Wendikidd's comments to a deleted answer, the following are all unexceptional...

> "Is this last year's?"
>    "Is this this week's?"
>    "Is this next month's?"
>    "Is this yesterday's?"
>    "Is this tomorrow's?"
>   etc., etc.

Note that there's normally an implied noun *after* the **'s** in each case *(model, issue, newspaper, etc.)*

But I doubt OP's *"some other time's"* would be considered "normal" by native speakers *any* context. If we wanted to express exactly that sense, we'd probably say *"It's **from** some other time"* (or more likely, *some **earlier/later** time*, if one of those two was obviously applicable).